# Error cannot work on multiple sections error?

Tags: excel, vba

I am creating a macros which grabs certain rows from a source sheet then copies the transpose of those rows into distinct columns in the destination sheet. I created the following however I am getting an Error at the CopyRange.Copy line saying "This Action won't work on multiple sections". I am unsure how to fix this. I just wanna grab specific rows out of a bunch in a spread and consolidate it into one transposed matrix to paste.

```
Option Explicit


Property Get wsSrc() As Worksheet
     Set wsSrc = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("MBI DSCR")
End Property
Property Get wSrc() As Workbook
Set wSrc = ActiveWorkbook
End Property
Property Get col() As Long
    col = wsSrc.Columns.Find(What:="MBI", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False).Column
End Property
Property Get col2() As Long
    col2 = wSrc.Sheets("Inputs").Columns.Find(What:="Deal Team", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False).Column
End Property

Property Get wsDest() As Worksheet
    Set wsDest = Workbooks("LBM_DSCT_DataLake.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet1")
End Property

Sub Extract()
'Dim wsSrc As Worksheet
'Set wsSrc = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("MBI DSCR")
Dim v As Range, ci As Range, ri As Range, oi As Range, tai As Range, rvp As Range, rvd As Range, cvp As Range, cvd As Range, cbp As Range, cbd As Range, egi As Range, te As Range, noi As Range, mbids As Range, ecf As Range, facr As Range, dscr As Range, CopyRange As Range


 Set v = wsSrc.Columns(col).Find(What:="DSCR Analysis", LookIn:=xlValues, _
                                      LookAt:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False)
        
    If v Is Nothing Then                     'didn't make a match with Find() ?
        Set v = wsSrc.Range("B40:G40")
    End If
    
     Set ci = wsSrc.Columns(col).Find(What:="Commercial Income", LookIn:=xlValues, _
                                      LookAt:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False)
        
    If ci Is Nothing Then                     'didn't make a match with Find() ?
        Set ci = wsSrc.Range("B40:G40")
    End If
    
     Set ri = wsSrc.Columns(col).Find(What:="Rental Income", LookIn:=xlValues, _
                                      LookAt:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False)
        
    If ri Is Nothing Then                     'didn't make a match with Find() ?
        Set ri = wsSrc.Range("B40:G40")
    End If
    
         Set oi = wsSrc.Columns(col).Find(What:="Other Income", LookIn:=xlValues, _
                                      LookAt:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False)
        
    If oi Is Nothing Then                     'didn't make a match with Find() ?
        Set oi = wsSrc.Range("B40:G40")
    End If
     
    Set tai = wsSrc.Columns(col).Find(What:="Total All Income", LookIn:=xlValues, _
                                      LookAt:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False)
        
    If tai Is Nothing Then                     'didn't make a match with Find() ?
        Set tai = wsSrc.Range("B40:G40")
    End If
    
     Set rvp = wsSrc.Columns(col).Find(What:="Rental Vacancy (%)", LookIn:=xlValues, _
                                      LookAt:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False)
        
    If rvp Is Nothing Then                     'didn't make a match with Find() ?
        Set rvp = wsSrc.Range("B40:G40")
    End If
    
    Set rvd = wsSrc.Columns(col).Find(What:="Rental Vacancy ($)", LookIn:=xlValues, _
                                      LookAt:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False)
        
    If rvd Is Nothing Then                     'didn't make a match with Find() ?
        Set rvd = wsSrc.Range("B40:G40")
    End If
    
    Set cvp = wsSrc.Columns(col).Find(What:="Commercial Vacancy (%)", LookIn:=xlValues, _
                                      LookAt:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False)
        
    If cvp Is Nothing Then                     'didn't make a match with Find() ?
        Set cvp = wsSrc.Range("B40:G40")
    End If
    
 Set cvd = wsSrc.Columns(col).Find(What:="Commercial Vacancy ($)", LookIn:=xlValues, _
                                      LookAt:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False)
        
    If cvd Is Nothing Then                     'didn't make a match with Find() ?
        Set cvd = wsSrc.Range("B40:G40")
    End If
    
     Set cbp = wsSrc.Columns(col).Find(What:="Concessions/Bad Debt (%)", LookIn:=xlValues, _
                                      LookAt:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False)
        
    If cbp Is Nothing Then                     'didn't make a match with Find() ?
        Set cbp = wsSrc.Range("B40:G40")
    End If
     Set cbd = wsSrc.Columns(col).Find(What:="Concessions/Bad Debt ($)", LookIn:=xlValues, _
                                      LookAt:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False)
        
    If cbd Is Nothing Then                     'didn't make a match with Find() ?
        Set cbd = wsSrc.Range("B40:G40")
    End If
     Set egi = wsSrc.Columns(col).Find(What:="Effective Gross Income", LookIn:=xlValues, _
                                      LookAt:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False)
        
        
    If egi Is Nothing Then                     'didn't make a match with Find() ?
        Set egi = wsSrc.Range("B40:G40")
    End If
     Set te = wsSrc.Columns(col).Find(What:="Total Expenses", LookIn:=xlValues, _
                                      LookAt:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False)
        
    If te Is Nothing Then                     'didn't make a match with Find() ?
        Set te = wsSrc.Range("B40:G40")
    End If
    
       Set noi = wsSrc.Columns(col).Find(What:="NOI", LookIn:=xlValues, _
                                      LookAt:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False)
        
    If noi Is Nothing Then                     'didn't make a match with Find() ?
        Set noi = wsSrc.Range("B40:G40")
    End If
    
       Set facr = wsSrc.Columns(col).Find(What:="Facility A Contractural Rate", LookIn:=xlValues, _
                                      LookAt:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False)
        
    If facr Is Nothing Then                     'didn't make a match with Find() ?
        Set facr = wsSrc.Range("B40:G40")
    End If
 Set mbids = wsSrc.Columns(col).Find(What:="MBI Debt Service", LookIn:=xlValues, _
                                      LookAt:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False)
        
    If mbids Is Nothing Then                     'didn't make a match with Find() ?
        Set mbids = wsSrc.Range("B40:G40")
    End If
        
     Set ecf = wsSrc.Columns(col).Find(What:="Excess Cash Flow", LookIn:=xlValues, _
                                      LookAt:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False)
        
    If ecf Is Nothing Then                     'didn't make a match with Find() ?
        Set ecf = wsSrc.Range("B40:G40")
    End If
     Set dscr = wsSrc.Columns(col).Find(What:="DSCR", LookIn:=xlValues, _
                                      LookAt:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False)
    Set dscr = wsSrc.Columns(col).FindNext(dscr)
        
    If dscr Is Nothing Then                     'didn't make a match with Find() ?
        Set dscr = wsSrc.Range("B40:G40")
    End If
    Set CopyRange = v
Set CopyRange = Union(CopyRange, ci)
Set CopyRange = Union(CopyRange, ri)
Set CopyRange = Union(CopyRange, oi)
Set CopyRange = Union(CopyRange, tai)
Set CopyRange = Union(CopyRange, rvp)
Set CopyRange = Union(CopyRange, rvd)
Set CopyRange = Union(CopyRange, cvp)
Set CopyRange = Union(CopyRange, cvd)
Set CopyRange = Union(CopyRange, cbp)
Set CopyRange = Union(CopyRange, cbd)
Set CopyRange = Union(CopyRange, egi)
Set CopyRange = Union(CopyRange, te)
Set CopyRange = Union(CopyRange, noi)
Set CopyRange = Union(CopyRange, facr)
Set CopyRange = Union(CopyRange, mbids)
Set CopyRange = Union(CopyRange, ecf)
Set CopyRange = Union(CopyRange, dscr)

CopyRange.Copy  '->>>>ERROR
      


Workbooks.Open "BOOK TO PASTE"
 wsDest.Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats, _
              Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=True

Range("A1").Value = "Date Added"
Range("B1").Value = "Name"
Range("C1").Value = "MBI DSCR Analysis"
Range("D1").Value = "Rental Income"
Range("E1").Value = "Commercial Income"
Range("F1").Value = "Other Income"
Range("G1").Value = "Total All Income"
Range("H1").Value = "Rental Vacancy (%)"
Range("I1").Value = "Rental Vacancy ($)"
Range("J1").Value = "Commercial Vacancy (%)"
Range("K1").Value = "Commercial Vacancy ($)"
Range("L1").Value = "Concessions/Bad Debt(%)"
Range("M1").Value = "Concessions/Bad Debt($)"
Range("N1").Value = "Effective Gross Income"
Range("O1").Value = "Total Expenses"
Range("P1").Value = "NOI"
Range("Q1").Value = "Facility A Contractural Rate"
Range("R1").Value = "MBI Debt Service"
Range("S1").Value = "Excess Cash Flow"
Range("T1").Value = "DSCR"

    Rows.AutoFit
    Columns.AutoFit
    
wSrc.Close SaveChanges:=True
End Sub
```

Comment: Have a look to https://www.automateexcel.com/how-to/command-cannot-be-used-multiple-selections/ - does this help? Also, having merged cell can cause this issues

Comment: this does not help

Comment: It would be easier to manage this if you copy and paste each row in turn, instead of building up a union'ed range and trying to do it in one shot.  There's a lot of repetition in your code which could be reduced by using an array of strings to pass to `Find()`, and looping over that array.

Comment: It looks like you're just copy/pasting any found row headers though (or the default range B40:G40)?  It's difficult to guess what should be happening here.

Comment: What should be happening is that it searches through a collum for a value, offsets it by one and copies the adjacent 6 spaces. If it is not counf it copies 6 blank cells to paste

Comment: I originally copied and pasted each row in turn however its complicating things with the program when I open and close the document

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Untested but something like this should be close:

```vb
Sub Extract()

    Dim arr, i As Long, f As Range, cPaste As Range
    Dim wbPaste As Workbook, wsPaste As Worksheet

    arr = Array("DSCR Analysis", "Commercial Income", "Rental Income", "Other Income", _
            "Total All Income", "Rental Vacancy (%)", "Rental Vacancy ($)", _
            "Commercial Vacancy (%)", "Concessions/Bad Debt (%)", "Concessions/Bad Debt ($)", _
            "Effective Gross Income", "Total Expenses", "NOI", "Facility A Contractural Rate", _
            "MBI Debt Service", "Excess Cash Flow", "DSCR")

    Set wbPaste = Workbooks.Open("BOOK TO PASTE")
    Set wsPaste = wbPaste.Sheets(1) 'for example
    wsPaste.Range("A1").Value = "Date Added"
    wsPaste.Range("B1").Value = "Name"
    
    Set cPaste = wsPaste.Range("C1") 'first header cell for pasted values
    
    For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
        
        cPaste.Value = arr(i) 'add the header
        Set f = wsSrc.Columns(col).Find(What:=arr(i), LookIn:=xlValues, _
                                    LookAt:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False)
        If Not f Is Nothing Then
            f.Offset(0, 1).Resize(1, 6).Copy 'copy 6 columns next to the found cell
            cPaste.Offset(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats, _
                             Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=True
        End If
        
        Set cPaste = cPaste.Offset(0, 1) 'next paste destination
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Its getting an error at wsSrc bc i think the active workbook is changed to the destination when it gets opened. This was the error I was running into earlier also. Unsure how to fix it. I wanna keep the first open, copy it all and then paste it bbut I dont think it will work,.

Comment: Things are going to be easier to manage if you just get a reference to the required workbook at the start of `Extract`, and keep using that reference.  If you instead call `wSrc`/`wsSrc` more than once there's no guarantee they'll return the same objects if you've opened/activated another workbook.  Also consider updating `col` and `col2` to take a workbook object as an argument, so you know they're using the right workbook.

Comment: how would one do this. Oh wait should i set wSRC to dim at the start with my other variables?

Comment: Yes - `Dim wsSource As Workbook: Set wsSource = ActiveWorkbook` then use `wsSource`